# Heroku doesn't recognize a column after mgirating

Tags: express, heroku, sequelize.js, production

I have deployed my app on Heroku, I've gone on Heroku and migrated. I'm trying to hit an endpoint with postman and for some reason `sequelize` gives an error: `errorMissingColumn`. I tested the endpoint on dev and it's working, I ran db:migrate *again* and Heroku says it's up to date but I'm still getting an `errorMissingColumn` issue. I'm not sure what else to do other than try to restart the Heroku app.

Comment: How did you run migration on heroku?

Comment: heroku run:detached sequelize db:migrate